# How to fix error "The view app.views.uploadform didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead."?

Tags: python, html, django, database, forms

So I have a form in a html document and I'm trying to use it to add a new item to my django database.

Here is the HTML form :

```
  <form method="POST" action="{% url 'uploadform' %}" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <label for="name">Name:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="name" name="name"><br>
    <label for="details">Details:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="details" name="details"><br>
    <label for="littype">Type of Literature:</label><br>
    <input type="text" id="littype" name="littype"><br>
    <label for="image">Cover:</label><br>
    <input type="file" id="image" name="image"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
```

Here is my views.py handling the function :

```
def uploadform(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.POST.get('name') and request.POST.get('details') and 
            request.POST.get('littype') and request.POST.get('image'):
            post = PostForm()
            post.name = request.POST.get('name')
            post.details = request.POST.get('details')
            post.littype = request.POST.get('littype')
            post.image = request.POST.get('image')
            if PostForm.is_valid():
                PostForm.save()
                return render(request, 'uploadform.html')
    else:
        return render(request, 'uploadform.html')
```

Here is my models.py even though i think the issue is in views.py :

```
class PostForm(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    details = models.TextField()
    littype = models.TextField()
    image = models.FileField(upload_to='app/files/')
```

And finally for the issue, im getting an error saying "The view app.views.uploadform didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.". I'm not sure what is causing the error and in addition,if there are any changes I have to make thats stopping the form from being turned into a new item in my database, I'd love to get help for that too.

Thanks for any answers! Have a good day!

Comment: Welcome to Stack!  Your view `uploadform` appears to have some atypical form handling.  Are you by chance using a model form class in a separate `forms.py` file?  It could be useful to share your template code where you have your `<form>` as well.

Comment: I did, but I couldnt seem to get any answers so I tried figuring out new ways of implementing the form. So i dont have the code anymore, my fault, shouldve kept it. Thanks for answering!

Comment: Sure thing.  It might help to set up a github repo - great for going back and getting old code!  If you're just getting into Django, I would recommend learning ModelForms, and checking out django-crispy-forms for styling (assuming you're using bootstrap).  Also in its current state, your view won't upload a file object.  I'd recommend working through this page on the docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/http/file-uploads/

Comment: Thank you, will do, I'll continue learning about these things so that I feel more comfortable with them but meanwhile I have drastically changed my code to make it simpler or a bit different and it is now working.

Comment: Glad to hear it!